# About VideoView in Android

Tags: android, android-videoview, android-framelayout

When you didn't set the videoPath but set a background,it look like this:
[image]

But When you set the videoPath of the videoview,it look like this:
[image]

I can't find the reason.
Here is my XML file:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/ic_background"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >
<VideoView
    android:id="@+id/video"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center" />   
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="right|bottom"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:padding="30dp" >
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageViewQRVD"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="40dp"
        android:background="@drawable/ic_qr_bg"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_qr" />
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageViewQR"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="40dp"
        android:background="@drawable/ic_qr_bg"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_qr" />
</LinearLayout>
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="right|bottom"
    android:layout_marginBottom="200dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="160dp"
    android:background="@drawable/ic_toast"
    android:text="扫我，在手机端继续查看验真信息"
    android:textColor="#ffffff" />
```